# Runnig VBScript using BatchScript from another path will cause ERROR

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

There is a VBS file in a folder and it uses the command below for launching an application:

```
WshShell.Run ".\Setup.exe"
```

lets name the vbs file to "Run.vbs"
Now If I Create a batch script and put it in the same path it will work good:

```
WScript Run.vbs
```

But If I came back just one folder and then try to launch the vbs file, it will give me an error that the specific file not found:

```
WScript Setups\Run.vbs
```

So it means Run.vbs file can not execute WshShell.Run ".\Setup.exe" because it seems it is running from another location! Even If I make the path correct and full (like the below command) it will not work via the batch file!

```
 WshShell.Run "C:\Folder\Setup.exe"
```

Where is the problem?

I even to try to fix the vbscript with the code below, but still it is not working if I launch it via batch script from another folder:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
dim fso: set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
dim CurrentDirectory
CurrentDirectory = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")
dim Directory
Directory = CurrentDirectory & "\Setup.exe"
WshShell.Run Chr(34) & Directory & Chr(34)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the value of `WshShell.CurrentDirectory` in your script. You can set this to whatever you'd like prior to calling `WshShell.Run`. The Shell object uses the `CurrentDirectory` property to deal with relative paths.

**Update:**

I'm getting confused by your folder hierarchy. Here's another way that doesn't rely on relative paths.

```
' Here's the folder where your script is at...
strScriptFolder = fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)

' Here's its parent folder...
strParentFolder = fso.GetParentFolderName(strScriptFolder)

' Here's how you can run setup.exe in the script folder...
WshShell.Run Chr(34) & strScriptFolder & "\setup.exe" & Chr(34)

' Here's how you can run setup.exe in the script's parent folder...
WshShell.Run Chr(34) & strParentFolder & "\setup.exe" & Chr(34)
```

Comment: Thank you Bond for your helps, I just updated my first post. It is not still working :(

Comment: But you're not changing the value of `WshShell.CurrentDirectory` in your code.

Comment: BTW, are you saying that your batch file is calling your script successfully? Or is the batch file not finding and launching your script?

Comment: Batch file is finding the script, But the script can not run setup.exe because it can not find it and the reason is that the batch file is trying to run the script from another directory: WScript UpperFolder\Run.vbs

Comment: Yep, changing `WshShell.CurrentDirectory` should fix that. But I'm surprised using the full path to `setup.exe` didn't work for you. An absolute pathname should work regardless.

Comment: WshShell.CurrentDirectory command will return the batch file directory. So I need to add foe example (\UpperFolder\Setup.exe) to WshShell.Run, how to do it?

Comment: So is `setup.exe` in the same folder as your batch file? And then your script is in a subfolder named `Setups`? If so, just use `WshShell.Run "setup.exe"`

Comment: no the setup.exe is located in UpperFolder\Setup.exe from batch directory and the vbs directory is the same from batch location, I mean UpperFolder\Run.vbs, so vbs and setup are in a same folder but batch is located in a previous folder.

Comment: Check my update. Might be easier to not deal with relative paths, calling processes, and `CurrentDirectory`.

Comment: Nice Guide Bond, now it is working Like a charm, you are a great VBScript Programmer ;)